# UIWebView - creating custom context menu?

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview, contextmenu

I added UIWebView control to my application.

To disable default context menu, I implemented webViewDidFinishLoad.

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheet[0];";
    NSString *addCSSRule = @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
        "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
        "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"
        "} else {"
        "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
        "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex;"
        "}"
        "}";
    ...
    NSString *insertRule = @"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-touch-callout: none;')";

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule];
    ...
}
```

But context menu of webview doesn't disappear. Anyone help me.

I also tried

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
```

It didn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Your method is named `webViewDidLoadFinished:`, not `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. Is it a typo in the question and/or in the code?

Comment: Sorry to ask this question, but I think it needs to be asked. Have you set the `UIWebView` `delegate` property and are you sure the code is being executed?

Comment: Sure. I add [webView setDelegate:self].

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain why you are trying to do with all this javascript ?
Just doing the following is not enough for you ?

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) sender {
    // Disable the defaut actionSheet when doing a long press
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

Comment: I've just noticed that this is not working with latest iOS beta version while it's working with iOS3 & iOS4 ... Are you using an iOS beta version ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to subclass the UIWebView. In your custom view, just implement the method canPerformAction:withSender like this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
  return NO;
}
```

then all menu items will disappear. If you just wanna show some of items, you should return YES for the specified item.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
  BOOL ret = NO;
  if (action == @selector(copy:)) ret = YES;
  return ret;
}
```

That gives you only "copy" when you long press a word in the view.