# Disabling context menu without disabling text selection

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, cordova

I'm working on an iPad app using phonegap. I'd like to disable the context menu when selecting text, but keep allowing the selection. So:

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
```

doesn't work, as it doesn't allow selections, and:

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:text;
```

still shows the menu.

The final aim is to hide that menu to show my own one, since (correct me if I'm wrong) the former can't be customized through javascript. If this can't be done, I think will end up studying the possibility of making a phonegap plugin for this purpose (if someone did it, is it feasible?)

Comment: Have to say that that might be something really undesirable from a UX perspective, but if you really want to do this you will need to implement a custom 'fake' selection I fear, because I would be greatly surprised if Apple would allow such an atrocity in any easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. I possibly didn't explain myself well. What we're trying to do is, after selecting text, adding new extra options to the menu so that tasks, like sharing, translating, etc., can be performed on the text (as you can see in loads of different apps, like iBooks e.g.). We're developing the the app using PhoneGap, which doesn't provide a way to modify the native context menu, so the options we're considering are creating a new javascript menu or a phonegap plugin that allows to modify the native one (which wouldn't be desirable, as we don't have objective-c experience)

Comment: In that case it might make more sense to show secondary options /aside/ of the normal menu. Because extending the native menu is perfectly fine, but presenting the user with different functionality from what he's expecting is fairly dangerous. You could (with the risk of it looking cluttered) show a second menu for example above the selected text (or as you said, develop a plugin, though I wouldn't advise that and a custom webview wrapper might be easier. Some of the answers here might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346565/uiwebview-creating-custom-context-menu).